# -f unknown reason for empty space

Tags: powershell

Basically I have a file containing names and lastnames, such as

> Sam, Anderson

I just want to change the order in which the names are shown to this:

> Anderson, Sam

This is my code:

```
$variable = Read-Host "would you like the names to be sorted in another way?" 'y,n'
if ($variable -eq 'y') {
    $Choice = Read-Host "would you like the names to be sorted based on last or first name?" 'l,f'

    if ($Choice -eq 'l') {
        $ergebnis | %{"{1}, {0}" -f $_.Split(',')} 
    }

    if ($Choice -eq 'f') {
        $ergebnis | %{"{0}, {1}" -f $_.Split(',')}
    }
}
```

When I run this `$ergebnis | %{"{0}, {1}" -f $_.Split(',')}` I get

```
Sam, Anderson
```

Then I change the positions `$ergebnis | %{"{1}, {0}" -f $_.Split(',')}`
and get this:

```
 Anderson, Sam
```

Can someone please help me figure out why I'm getting an empty space in the output when starting with position 1?

`$ergebnis` is the variable containing the names.

Comment: Because you are using split at `,` [comma]. So the space is already there. You have to either `trim()` it or use `regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are splitting at the comma which includes the space. You should use .Trim() as shown below:

```
$ergebnis | %{"{1}, {0}" -f $_.split(',').Trim()}
```

Comment: @user11124311 Please mark as answered for future users experiencing the same issue :)

Answer (score 3):

As others have pointed out, you're splitting the string at commas, and only at commas, thus preserving the leading space before the surname. Meaning that running `"{0}, {1}" -f $_.Split(',')` should give you a result of

```
Sam,  Anderson
```

with 2 spaces after the comma, whereas `"{1}, {0}" -f $_.Split(',')` should give you a result of

```
 Anderson, Sam
```

with one space after the comma and another before the surname.

You can trim leading/trailing whitspace after splitting the string, as has been suggested already, but that requires PowerShell v3 or newer, as it makes use of [member enumeration](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/) to call `Trim()` on all results of the `Split()` operation.

An alternative is to use the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-3.0) operator with a regular expression that includes whitespace in the pattern by which the string is split. That way whitespace before or after the comma is automatically removed. For good measure you could `Trim()` the input string to remove spurious whitespace at the beginning or end of the string before splitting it.

```
$ergebnis | ForEach-Object { "{0}, {1}" -f ($_.Trim() -split '\s*,\s*') }
```

Comment: i really appreciate the detailed explanation, it made things much clearer, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Another aspect of splitting either with the `.split()` method or `-split` operator is,
that when using only index [0,1] of the result you'll end up with only partial input if there is more than one comma.

Both variants do have a parameter to limit the number of splits.

While moving away from your title, you could also use the `-join`operator
to reattch the parts in reversed order:

```
$Neues_Ergebnis = $Ergebnis | ForEach-Object {($_.Trim() -split '\s*,\s*',2)[1,0] -join ', '}
```

Comment: That is a very interesting add to the post and it will definitely come in handy, thank you for sharing!